Norm on subset of vector space of all bounded functions in n dimensions
Let $\mathcal{M}:=\{f:X\rightarrow \Delta^n\}$, where $X\subseteq \mathbb{R}^m$ and $\Delta^n$ is the $n$-dim probability simplex.
These functions are bounded in an intuitive sense, however, I fail to make it formal since boundedness requires a norm: $f$ is bounded if there exists $M>0$ such that $\|f(x)\|\leq M$ for all $x$. However, $\mathcal{M}$ fails to be a vector space so it cannot be a normed space, so we dont have a norm that we can use to define boundedness.
So my first idea would be to view it as a subspace of the set $\mathcal{V}=\{f:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n: \exists M>0, \|f(x)\|\leq M\}$ which is the set of all bounded functions. This is as far as I know a vector space and with the supremum norm a normed space.
Can I then use the supremums norm from the space $\mathcal{V}$ for my set $\mathcal{M}$? In particular, could I define a metric via $d(f, g) = \|f-g\|, f, g \in \mathcal{M}$? I am asking this because since $\mathcal{M}$ is not a vector space the inverse i.e., $-g$ need not be defined in $\mathcal{M}$ so I wonder if this is well defined then?

Of course you can. Every subset of a metric space inherits from it a metric, by restriction. You won't have a norm on $\mathcal M$ (this wouldn't make sense, as you observed) but still, a metric.

@AnneBauval Thank you. If we consider the subspace of $\mathcal{V}$ of all bounded functions to $\mathbb{R}^n$ that are measurable. Is this still a vector space?

Yes: it is closed under $+$ and $k\cdot$ ($\forall k\in\Bbb R$).

@AnneBauval thank you! So one thing that I am not sure about in the definitino of the vector space of all bounded functions: Do we fix one $M\in \mathbb{R}$ and only consider all the functions that are bounded by this $M$ or do we consider all functions that are bounded by whatever $M\in\mathbb{R}$?

You have to allow every $M$ (like you did with your $\exists M>0$), otherwise it won't be closed under those two operations.
